# Logging queries and hits in Elasticsearch

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin

We want to use [Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/webinars/introduction-elk-stack) to display queries and hits from another Elasticsearch.

Setting every slowlog threshold to 0ms gives us the query but not the number of hits

```
index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.warn: 0ms
....
```

Are there any ways of getting the query and the number of hits on each query straight from Elastsearch?

Comment: Here's an article explaining how to monitor search queries using Packetbeat: https://www.elastic.co/blog/monitoring-the-search-queries